# How do I download mail folders from command line?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, server, software-recommendation, mail

I want to download my mails (batch download) which are located in a "sample" folder on my yahoo mail to local folder on my harddisk.

Is there a command-line client which allows me to download mails from this folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of tools that can do this. Some can do both: imap and pop3. Some are limited to pop3 or imap.

As an example take a look at getmail: http://www.howtogeek.com/138713/how-to-backup-your-gmail-account-using-your-ubuntu-pc/ (in standard repo (xubuntu 13.1 is getmail4)

Another one is "offlineimap" that can copy mails from a imap server to a local dir: https://popey.com/blog/posts/2010/12/30/backup-email-with-offlineimap.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, i used getmail and IMAP protocol to download my mails :*